# Android Robolectric library for unit test startFragment() method required android.app and I am using android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android

Required Type android.app Fragment Provided android.support.v4.app.Fragment. startFragment Method is depecreated. what is alternative to use startFragment() method in robolectric Unit test